# Counting data across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count the number of cells with data in a column.

I have to count these cells from all the workbooks.

For example, I have 2 workbooks: WB1 and WB2.

- Worksheet WS1 with data in A1, A2, A3, A4
- Worksheet WS2 with data in A1, A2.
- My output should show 6.

How can I count this?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim paths(), wbs() As Workbook
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sh, rn, k

    paths = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Please browse all the Rawdata files")

    For x = 1 To UBound(paths)
        ReDim wbs(UBound(paths))
        Set wbs(x) = Workbooks.Open(paths(x))

        Set sh = wbs(x).Sheets("Role ID - Description")
        Set rn = sh.UsedRange
        k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1 - 1
        wbs(x).Close
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: what kind of _"trouble"_ do you have?

Answer (score 3):

You are not maintaining your counter from sheet to sheet for a workbook (e.g., k = k + 1 to iterate by 1).  Inside of your workbook you would want something such as:

```
dim i as long, k as long, lr as long
With Workbook("blah")
    For i = 1 to .sheets.count
        With .Sheets(i)
            lr = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
            k = k + lr
        End with
    Next i
    'output k to some destination
    k=0
End with
```

---

**Edit1:**

Adding counta scenario per Kubie's recommendation (untested):

```
dim i as long, k as long, cnta as long
With Workbook("blah")
    For i = 1 to .sheets.count
        With .Sheets(i)
            cnta = application.counta(.columns(1))
            k = k + cnta
        End with
    Next i
    'output k to some destination
    k=0
End with
```

Comment: since the goal appears to be *counting the number of cells with data*, maybe should use `CountA` instead of finding last row for each sheet? (unless no rows are blank)

Comment: @Kubie Good point; i had assumedfrom the OP that the lines were contiguous, per the example, which wouldn't necessarily be correct.  The same scenario where k is maintained would exist... i'll add your scenario, too, just to be safe.